# Print text within two RegEx

Tags: html, perl

How can I print the text starting at the occurence of the
reg expression $START_REGEX till $END_REGEX?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use warnings;

package HTMLStrip;
use base "HTML::Parser";
use LWP::Simple;

my $START_REGEXP = 'To the current program';
my $END_REGEXP = 'Please choose';

sub text {
    my ($self, $text) = @_;
    print $text;
}

my $p = new HTMLStrip;
$p->parse_file("index.html");
$p->eof
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use groups to get the value in between two phrases:

```
To the current program(.*)Please choose
```

Then, the value will be stored in `$1,$2, etc`

[Here is the rubular](http://rubular.com/r/ISt70fSsOX)

For something that is more perl-cut-and-paste ([from this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3039920/regex-indexed-arrayed-named-capture-groups))

```
my @values = ($text=~/$START_REGEXP(.*)$END_REGEXP/gm);
print "The first value is $values[0]\n";
```

I am not a PERL dev, so I am extrapolating. You will have to do your own further research if some sort of syntax is off.

Comment: If I add $text =~ /$START_REGEXP(.*)$END_REGEXP/; Nothing changes, it still prints everything and not the text between those phrases.